# Modifying Records into Database Through Jtable

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtable, resultset

I created a Jtable using Netbeans 7.1.
The table created a default model as below

```
table.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
        }
    ));
```

I also added the following lines of code to populate data from an Sqlite Database.

```
public void tabl()
{
  try
  {
    stmt=conn.createStatement();
    String sql2="SELECT * FROM students";
    rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql2);
    int n=0;
    while(rs.next())
    {  

      table.setValueAt(rs.getString(1),n,0);
      table.setValueAt(rs.getString(2),n,1);
      table.setValueAt(rs.getString(3),n,2);
      table.setValueAt(rs.getString(4),n,3);
      n++;
    }
  }
  catch(SQLException e)
  {

  }
}
```

My quiz is How do I now make the `JTable` able to Update and delete records...with the default model.I am new to table Models.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data

Comment: @Xcoder: write `rs.getXXX("column_title")` in code. it will remove further errors due to database tables or view manipulations.

Answer (score 1):

```
DefaultTableModel dmReset = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
try {
    stmt=conn.createStatement();
    String sql2="SELECT * FROM students";
    rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql2);
    while (rs.next()) {
          Vector v = new Vector();
          v.add(rs.getString(1));
          v.add(rs.getString(2));
          v.add(rs.getString(3));
          v.add(rs.getString(4));
          dmReset.addRow(v);
          }
    } catch (Exception e) {
          System.err.println(e.toString());
    }
```

Note : Use full column headers in `rs.getXXX()` methods instead of column indexes.
for more details on `TableModel` you can refer [this document.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html)

If you want to get other types of data like Float, int etc... a switch case can be added with this,
you can find example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629198/creating-jtable-from-database).

Answer (score 0):

you have to create statement like this

```
conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
                    ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
```

and also note that select * FROM table; always returns read only result set. instead query should be select column1,columnn FROM table;

Comment: @peter How do I update changes with a button I just created.?