# Creating JTable from database

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtable, odbc

I am trying to generate  a JTable in my Inventory system and I wanna display records from my database table to the JTable when user click the view bill button,[Image of my Billing Form](http://designluster.com/screenshoot%20bill%20form.jpg).

[image]

Database structure

**Bill_Master**

1. Bill_Id (Primary  Key INT ):-Stores Bill Number
2. Bill_Date (Date): Stores Date Of Bill
3. Customer_Name ( VARCHAR(50)): Customer Name
4. Total_amt (NUMBER(6)) :Total Bill Amount
5. Cash_Disc (Number(2)):Discount
6. Grand_Total(Number(6)):Grand Total (Total-Discnt)
7. UID(VARCHAR(10)) Stores Who Generated the bill.(EMPLOYEE  ID)

   **Bill_Details**
8. Bill_Detailid(INT PRIMARY KEY) Detailed Bill No.1
9. Bill_Id(Foreign Key To Bill_Master)
10. Item_Id(Foreign Key To Stock)
11. Qty (INT)
12. Rate(number(5))
13. Total(Number(5))

I want to display the detailed bill when user clicks on View Bill Button by using the query

`Select * from  Bill_Master Inner join Bill_Details on Bill_Master.Bill_Id=Bill_Details.Bill_Id.`

Database Connection Type:ODBC
Please help to generate the table.

Comment: Start by taking a look at [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html). I would suggest you should create a POJO the represents the data you will collect from the database, it will make it easier to manage in the long run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get data from ResultSet and Add Each row of table to the DefaultTableModel using vector.

Like following Example:

```
try {
        ResultSetMetaData rm = rs.getMetaData();
        int j = rm.getColumnCount();
        JTable table=new JTable();
        int rowCount = table.getRowCount();
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
        Vector v = null;
        if (rowCount == 0) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                v = new Vector();

                for (int i = 1; i <= j; i++) {
                    String type = rm.getColumnTypeName(i);
                    // System.out.println(type);
                    switch (type) {
                        case "FLOAT":
                            v.add(rs.getFloat(i));
                            break;
                        case "COUNTER":
                            v.add(rs.getInt(i));
                            break;
                        case "VARCHAR":
                            v.add(rs.getString(i));
                            break;
                        case "INTEGER":
                            v.add(rs.getInt(i));
                            break;
                        case "DATETIME":
                            v.add(rs.getString(i));
                            break;
                        case "MEDIUMINT":
                            v.add(rs.getInt(i));
                            break;
                        case "LONGBLOB":
                            v.add(rs.getTime(i));
                            break;
                        default:
                            v.add(rs.getString(i));
                    }
                }
                model.addRow(v);
            }
```

Here model is the DefaultTableModel of the Your table on which you have to add the row.
do you get my point? Or any doubt.?

Comment: I didn't created any table for this. I want create and display the table at the time of button click. Can above code do this? I am beginner in java. If you can please explain it little more.

Comment: Thank you. Is there anyway to popup the entire table using another frame?

Comment: It is easy. You have to create a new JFrame and pass this table as parameter in constructor and add this table into frame and set this frame.

Comment: @Aswin, there is no need for the switch statement. Just get the Object from the ResultsSet and add it to the Vector.

Comment: @chintan Hi. I implimented your codeand try to display it using a JOptionPane.'JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout());        
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
            scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
            panel.add(scrollPane);
           JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel, "Bill Details", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);' But it displaying a blank pag. Can you help me to solve this issue

Comment: scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        jp.add(scroll);
        jp.setSize(800, 800);
        JScrollPane jsc = new JScrollPane(jp);
        JFrame jf=new JFrame();
        jf.getContentPane().add(jsc, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setSize(500,500);

Answer (score 1):

```
while(resultset.next()){
    // iterate through the results, get necessary column values add them into table model
    Vector v = new Vector();
    v.add(resultset.getString(0));
     .
     .
    model.addRow(v)

}

table.setModel(model)
```

follow some tutorials on how to use jTable