# How to display the JTable created from Database as like a message dialog

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable

I want to display the JTable table created from My Bill_Master database as like a message dialog in `JOptionPane.showMessageDiaolg`. I tried to display it using a new JFrame,but it was unsuccessful.

```
     JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout());        
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
        panel.add(scrollPane);
       JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel, "Bill Details",JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
```

Comment: “but it was unsuccessful” *define* “unsuccessful”

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating JTable from database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629198/creating-jtable-from-database)

Comment: If you want to add the table to an option pane then use an option pane. The code you posted is using a JFrame. You can add any component to a JOptionPane. Read the JOPtionPane API for the proper parameters to use. I would add the scrollpane to the option pane in case scrollbars are required to see the entire table.

Comment: @Holger I mean it didn't shows the table. It only showing a blank frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this logic.
You should use `JDialog` instead of using `JPanel`. And then add `JTable` object on it. It will create custom dialog same as `JOptionPane`.
I think this link will help you...
http://www.coderanch.com/t/332805/GUI/java/dialog-box-JTable