# Using JTables in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jdbc, jtable

I want to display the data out of my result set into a `JTable`. 
When I run the following code the table doesn't update.

```
 public void getHouses(int price) {
    Connection conn;


    ArrayList<Integer> ID = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<String> Price = new ArrayList<String>();



    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Houses");
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rec = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Houses WHERE Price <= " + price + "");

        while (rec.next()) {
            ID.add(rec.getInt("ID"));
            Price.add(rec.getString("Price"));
        }


        String[] columnNames = {"House ID", "House Price"};
        Object[][] rows = new Object[ID.size()][2];

        for (int i = 0; i < ID.size(); i++) {
            rows[i][0] = ID.get(i);
            rows[i][1] = Price.get(i);
        }

        jTable1 = new JTable(rows, columnNames);

        statement.close();
    } catch (SQLException se) {
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnf) {}
}
```

NOTE!
I added the `JTable` to the gui by drag and drop.
I also tested that my resultset has the data in it.

Comment: You create a new `JTable` but you don't add it to anything

Comment: @MadProgrammer The JTable is already added i just create a new instance of it?

Comment: check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19634168/1686291)...

Comment: Exactly, so you now have one that is on the screen another one which isn't...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Okay so i added the JTable but still Nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to learn about OP Swing `MVC` pattern, you need to declare a `TableModel` which your data store then set it to your table, like:

```
TableModel myData = new DefaultTableModel(columnVector, dataVector);
jTable1.setModel(myData);
```

Read more about [DefaultTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html)

Comment: Actually, I think it would be more correct to say that the OP needs to learn about MVC generally, +1

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yea your right, `TableModel` just applying the `MVC` pattern concepts into `JTable`.

Comment: unfortunately i am not allowed to use vectors as told by my instructor.

Comment: @Kobus, there are a lot of constructor that take other types of argument for your data. you could use `DefaultTableModel(Object[][] data, Object[] columnNames)`. you can read more about it in the link above.